# Call actual function from blur()

Tags: jquery, callback, handle, blur

I'm trying to write some jquery that will call a function when an object is blurred.  Because of some of the requirement in my underlying code, I need to call a function, like this:

```
$("object").blur(myFunction());
```

instead of like this:

```
$("object").blur(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

Unfortunately, binding the blur event using the first method doesn't work.  It actually runs the method on page load, and then never binds the function.  What am I doing wrong here?

I've set up a jsfiddle that demonstrates my problem, if it helps you visualize. http://jsfiddle.net/WskKJ/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("object").blur(myFunction);
```

dont use () when u pass a delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
$("object").blur(function() {
  myFunction();
});
```

Comment: While this will work, there's really no need to create a new anonymous function just to call another function.

Comment: Yeah in this case that's true.  I suggested it this way because the comment in the poster's code said //do stuff.  Just in case you need to do any more work before calling myFunction()